# Displaying both text and data from db in a tooltip d3

Tags: d3.js

I am using the tooltip function in d3. I want to take data from the database and display it in the tooltip but with headings before each bit of information. This is the code so far which just displays all the info on one line with no headings:

```
function mouseHandler(d, i) {

d3.json("connection3.php?paperID="+d.ID, function(error,data) {

                var myList = ""
                data.forEach(function(d) {
                    myList = myList + d.ID + d.TITLE + d.AUTHOR;
                    })

                tooltip.transition()
                    .duration(200)
                    .style("opacity", .9);
                tooltip.html(myList)

            })
            }
```

I want use something like this `var html = "<p> ID: </p> <br> <p>TITLE: </p><br><p> Authors: </p><br>";` so that each heading is followed by the relevant information from the database and each heading and info is on separate lines. But I cant seem to get this working. I tried doing

```
var html = "<p> ID: "myList + d.ID" " </p> <br> <p>TITLE: </p><br><p> Authors: </p><br>";
```

But I get an error about an unidentified string. I know this is probably a very stupid question but I have been stuck on this for ages! I am new to d3 so any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use d3.keys function.

```
var myList = ""
data.forEach(function(d) {
    d3.keys(d).forEach(function(key){
       myList = myList +"<p> "+key+": "+ d[key] +" </p><br>"
    });
});
```

> d3.keys(object)
>
> Returns an array containing the property names of the specified object
>   (an associative array).

Reference: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#d3_keys

```js
var data = [{id: 123, title: 'item1'},{id: 456, title: 'item2'}];
var myList = ""
data.forEach(function(d) {
  d3.keys(d).forEach(function(key) {
    myList = myList + "<p> " + key.toUpperCase() + ": " + d[key] + " </p>"
  });
});
document.write(myList);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thats great thank u! When there are multiple authors the tooltip the info is replicated and just the author is changed.How would I go about only allowing the information to be listed once and all authors go on the same line? Its prob an issue with my query that when there are multiple authors for an ID it returns all info twice with the author name changed.If you knew how I could fix this that would be great `SELECT * from `authors` INNER JOIN (SELECT ID,TITLE from papers GROUP BY ID) as addtitle ON authors.ID = addtitle.ID where authors.ID = ".$_GET["paperID"];`@Gilsha